# iPhone - Data fetching from Parent table using Child Object in core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I have two Data Base which is shown in the attacted picture [image]

I have the NewRelease Object and i want to get it's parent Object which is Contract. Means i want to know that this NewRelease Object belong to which Contract. I am unable to fetch the data can any one guide be what should be a rite predicate for this situation. I am successfully fetching the data for it's inverse case in NewRelease and Signature Table using this predicate Line

```
NSArray *filterResults = [mutableFetchResults filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hasNewReleases = %@",aNewRelease]];
```

where aNewRelease is my NewRelease Object now how can i fetch data from Contracts Table using NewRelease Object.

There is "One to Many" Relation between NewRelease and Contracts such that one single Contract can belong to multiple NewReleases. Npw as i have mention above i have newRelease Object and i want to know that this newRelease belong to which Contract.

Comment: Your diagram does not make sense.  It shows relationship links, but no relationship properties in the entities.  The only one there is Signature.ofNewRelease, yet there should be something for the other relationships.  Fix your model, and you should be able to easily access "Contact" via the relationship from "NewRelease" to "Contract."

Comment: Jody i have mention this "There is "One to Many" Relation between NewRelease and Contracts such that one single Contract can belong to multiple NewReleases. Npw as i have mention above i have newRelease Object and i want to know that this newRelease belong to which Contract." .

Comment: I know what you have stated.  I am saying that your statement and your diagram do not match.  Furthermore, the diagram itself is inconsistent.  It shows "links" for relationships that are not present in the entity descriptions themselves.  Until you fix these inconsistencies in your question, I doubt you will get much real assistance (that is more than a guess) because it just does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add relationship between NewRelease and Contract table , then whenever you will fetch data from NewRelease or Contract entity ,you can access the data with its associated relationship.
Check the following example : http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: i have already a one to many relationship between NewRelease and Contract. Javal Nanda i am using CoreData first time in my iPhone Application and i am bit weak in it can you explain be little more

Comment: but in your database diagram i can only see relationship between Signature and NewRelease (i.e ofNewRelease ) have you refered to the tutorial of the link i posted? you will get a detailed idea from it.

Comment: yeah i have refered it. There is a Relationship of "One to Many" between Contract and New Release Table in which Contract is a parent Table, ,means one single contact can be associated to multiple NewReleases. now i have the NewRelease Object and i want to know that this new Release belong to which table

Comment: if the name of the relationShip is for example aContractRelationShip in your NewRelease table ,and you have setup inverse relationship then when you will fetch NewRelease data , for e.g newReleaseObj is your retrieved managed object , by accessing [newReleaseObj valueForKey:@"aContractRelationShip"] you will get the contract object associated with it. i.e    //NSManagedObject associatedContractObj = [newReleaseObj valueForKey:@"aContractRelationShip"]; and then you have all the information from that object

Comment: thank You.... thankx alot Javal Nanda you have solved my problem..... thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

you should add an attribute naming contracId in NewRelease. So that there is always an id of contract for each NewRelease object and hence you can easily fetch data for each new release using the contractID.

chill :)